# Vite documentation recommends for ssl "creating your own certificates" but how do you do that?

Tags: security, ssl, heroku, https, vite

I have built an Ionic/React/Vite pwa app that has a Flask/Python backend.  I've deployed the pwa and backend on Heroku separately.  Everything works fine, except I want whoever goes to my pwa app to be forced to use HTTPS.  As opposed to the current situation where you can use my pwa app with both http and https depending on what you type in.  That's where I thought the `server.https` portion of the vite documentation could help me here:  https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html

I set the parameter to true and it doesn't work.  I get code H13 errors in my logs.

The server.https section says:

"A valid certificate is needed. For a basic setup, you can add @vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl to the project plugins, which will automatically create and cache a self-signed certificate. But we recommend creating your own certificates."

How do you create your own certificates?  There's no examples or description on how to do this.  I have a certificate set up through Heroku.  Do I plug that into the config settings here somehow?  Am I even approaching this correctly?  The docs recommend that plugin for a basic setup but right after say they don't recommend it, so I haven't used it.

edit:

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test.e2e": "cypress run",
    "test.unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "5.2.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.2.3",
    "@capacitor/geolocation": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@ionic/react": "^7.0.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "pullstate": "^1.25.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-router": "^5.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "reselect": "^4.1.8",
    "swiper": "^10.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^4.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "cypress": "^12.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.65.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "4.4.9",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "^0.16.4",
    "vitest": "^0.32.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

and this is my vite config:

```
export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {

  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())
  console.log('in the beginning', env)


  


  return {

  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    https: true
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    legacy(),
    VitePWA({registerType: 'autoUpdate'})
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/setupTests.ts',
  }
   
}});
```

also, my Procfile:

```
web: npm start
```

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right approach on Heroku. [Your application should listen for HTTP requests *only*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#routing):

> Inbound requests are received by a load balancer that offers SSL termination. From here they are passed directly to a set of routers.
>
> The routers are responsible for determining the location of your application’s web [dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) and forwarding the HTTP request to one of these dynos.

Heroku's load balancer and routers take care of the HTTPS connection, unwrap requests as necessary, and pass plain HTTP along to your application:

```
           HTTP or HTTPS                   HTTP
Internet <---------------> Heroku Router <------> Your application
```

Your application just needs to redirect URLs that start with `http://` to `https://`. ([Heroku doesn't do this for you](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls).)

Exactly how you do this depends on how you are serving your application. Heroku doesn't support static sites natively, so users sometimes use a small PHP server or similar to serve them. Or they use other hosts for their client applications that are better-suited to static sites.